# JavaScript print for CKEditor content

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

**Html:**

```
<textarea name="Editor" class="ckeditor" id="aboutme">@Model.Content</textarea>


<button type="button" onclick="Print()">Print</button>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function Print() {
        printcontent($("#printDiv").html());
    }
    function printcontent(content) {

        var i = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;

        i.editor.execCommand('print');

  }
```

I tried above javascript code in order to print ckeditor content however it did not work for me.

How can i print ckeditor content on button click ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**Print addon**](http://ckeditor.com/addon/print)?

> This plugin activates the printing function. A standard operating
>   system printing pop-up window will appear where you will be able to
>   choose the printer as well as all relevant options.

Then you will be able to call `print` command to open print dialog.

To call command on your custom button you could use:

```
<textarea name="Editor" class="ckeditor" id="aboutme">@Model.Content</textarea>
<button type="button" onclick="print('aboutme')">Print</button>
<script>
    function print(editorName) {
        var editor = CKEDITOR.instances[editorName];           
        editor.execCommand('print');
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$scope.print = function () {        
  CKEDITOR.instances.certificate_editor.execCommand('print');
};
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn-primary" ng-click="print()">Print</button>
```